# Erro ao pegar input de um <form> com mongoose/nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

Olá, recentemente comecei a aprender node.js e estou usando o mongoose para integrar com o db 'mongodb', e nessa aplicação estou tentando pegar dados de 2  e inserir esses dados no banco, fiz um  name e um slug, o problema é que os dados só são inseridos no banco quando eu uso um "default: 'undefined name' " na parte de cadastrar o nome, e a parte do slug (que seria o segundo ) entra no banco sem nenhum problema mesmo sem o comando 'default' na hora de definir as caracteristicas, e quando eu tiro o 'default' do name, ele me mostra o seguinte erro no cmd:

Error saving category: ValidationError: name: Path `name` is required.

Agradeço se me ajudarem!

Segue abaixo o codigo:

app.js:

```
// Constante que recebe o express
   const express = require('express');
// Constante que recebe o handlebars
    const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
// Constante que recebe o bodyparses
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// Constante que recebe o mongoose
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Constante que recebe a função do express
    const app = express();
// Constante para chamar rotas de um arquivo externo (usar nome do arquivo no nome da constante)
    const admin = require('./routes/admin.js');
// Constante para receber modulo de arquivos estaticos e trabalhar com diretorios
    const path = require('path');

// Configurações
// Configuração do BodyParser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Configuração do HandleBars
    app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
// Configuração do Mongoose
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/blogapp', {useNewUrlParser: true}).then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error to connect: ' + err);
    });
// Configuração do caminho (Path) na pasta public
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Rotas
// Comando para chamar um grupo de rotas em um arquivo especifico
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Index Route!');
    });

    app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Post Lists!');
    })

    app.use('/admin', admin);

// Outros
// Constante da porta localhost
    const PORT = 8081;
// Função para abrir o servidor na porta selecionada
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log('Server running!');
    })
```

category.js:

```
 // Constante que recebe o mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Constante para ser chamada na hora de criar novos schemas/tables    
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Constante para criar um novo schema
const Category = new Schema({
    // Atributo do schema
    name: {
        // Tipo do schema
        type: String,
        // Definir se o schema é obrigatorio ou não
        required: true,
        // Definir um valor/texto padrão caso o campo não seja preenchido
        default: 'Undefined name'
    },
    slug: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});

// Comando para sincronizar os comandos do mongo com o mongoose
mongoose.model('categories', Category);
```

admin.js:

```
//Carregamento de modulos
// Constante que recebe o express
const express = require('express');
// Constante para cirar rota em arquivo externo
const router = express.Router();
// Constante que recebe o mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Comando para chamar o path 'models'
require('../models/Category');
// Constante para importar o arquivo Category.js com os comandos do mongo da pasta 'models'
const Category = mongoose.model('categories');

// Rota principal para o painel administrativo
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('admin/index')
    });
// Rota para listar posts
    router.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Post page!');
    });
// Rota para cadastrar categorias
    router.get('/categories', (req, res) => {
        res.render('admin/categories');
    });
// Rota onde são adicionadas as categorias
    router.get('/categories/add', (req, res) => {
        res.render('admin/addcategories');
    });
// Rota onde as categorias adicionadas aparecem
    router.post('/categories/new', (req, res) => {
        const newCategory = {
            nome: req.body.name,
            slug: req.body.slug
        };
        new Category(newCategory).save().then(() => {
            console.log('Category successfully saved');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error saving category: ' + err);
        })
    })

 // Exportação final para sincronizar as rotas (esse comando sempre devera ficar no final do codigo!)
module.exports = router
```

addcategories.handlebars:

#### New category:

Name: 
        
    Slug: 
        
        
    Create cateogry

Comment: Posta aí o formulário onde insere os valores, pq não há necessidade nenhuma de se utilizar o **default**.

Comment: <h3>New category: </h3>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
    <form action="/admin/categories/new" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Category name" class="form-control">
    <label for="slug">Slug: </label>
        <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="Slug of category" class="form-control">
        <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create cateogry</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, fica meio difícil de fazer uma análise mais adequada, mas, acredito que o problema aí é que aqui neste trecho de código:

```
const newCategory = {
    nome: req.body.name,       <= está utilizando o atributo nome
    slug: req.body.slug
};
```

Mas na declaração do atributo na classe **Category**:

```
name: {                        <= está utilizando name
    // Tipo do schema
    type: String,
    // Definir se o schema é obrigatorio ou não
    required: true,
    // Definir um valor/texto padrão caso o campo não seja preenchido
    default: 'Undefined name'
},
```

Comment: Cara, total falta de atenção minha, nem sei como te agradecer, estava tentando resolver esse codigo desde cedo, muito obrigado mesmo!!! :D

Comment: Normal man, pra quem desenvolve este tipo de erro é normal, ficamos muito concentrados em algo que as vezes o erro é uma coisa boba, mas, levamos um tempo até descobrir. Sucesso aí!